# Mock function used in flask request handler

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, python-unittest

I'm trying to mock the `upload_image` function called in a flask request handler from my test file.

However, with my current implementation, the original function is still called in the request handler and does not return the mocked return value. How can I mock this function from my `test.py` file?

The code:

`tests/test.py`

```
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_image_upload(test_client):
    with patch("app.utils.upload_image", 'test_path'):
        test_file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/test_file.png'
        f = open(test_file_path, 'rb')

        data = {
            'num-files': 1,
            'test_file.png': f
        }

        response = test_client.post('/file/upload', data=data)
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

`app/files/handler.py`

```
from utils import upload_image
@app.route('/file/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    # should be returning 'test_path', but is actually uploading the file and returning a URL
    file_url = upload_image(image)
    return jsonify({'file_url': file_url})
```

Comment: I believe you should be patching `app.files.handler.upload_image` because you are importing the function into the current namespace. You would patch `app.utils.upload_image` if you did `import utils; utils.upload_image()`

Comment: yeah, that did it. Thanks!